# Fitting instrument for time series analysis

Tags: python, time, series, analysis

i am looking for the fitting statistical instrument to use for analysing posting behavior in dependence of stock prices.

My data frame looks like this:

| Time | Price | Topic A | Topic B | Topic C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12:00 | 30 | 0,5 | 0,3 | 0,2 |
| 13:00 | 40 | 0,8 | 0,1 | 0,1 |
| 14:00 | 38 | 0,8 | 0,2 | 0,0 |
| 15:00 | 35 | 0,7 | 0,3 | 0,0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I found some interesting significant correlation for the overall data as my hypothesis is formulated like: If price rises, the people submit more of type postings containing "topic A". So Topic A would be the dependent variable and price and the other exogenous ones.

Now my reviewer asks me to use time series analysis with statistical tests. I am quite lost as i have never used time series analysis until now.

Most of the help i found online (looking for "multiple regression time series analysis") was around machine learning and predicting further variables. I stumble across things like stationarity tests and ARMA but i am still lost on what would be the best way to apply here.

Would you experts have any idea for this situation?

Comment: This questions seems better suited for the Cross-Validated site at https://stats.stackexchange.com, as it relates to methods of data analysis  and not to programming.  Once you know the type of analysis you need to do and have a question regarding how to do that in a specific programming language, then StackOverflow is the right place.

Comment: Maybe this thread on CrossValidated is relevant to your scenario?  About time series correlation.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133155/how-to-use-pearson-correlation-correctly-with-time-series

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.